# Why $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan(x/2) dx= \ln 2$

Tags: integration

I don't know why 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan\frac{x}2\ dx= \ln 2.$$
How can i solve this to get that answer?

Comment: What is the antiderivative of $\tan{x}$? Start with that.

Comment: Please edit the question to include additional background and motivation. Also, please include a description of what you have already tried. These things help make the question more compelling, help others find it, and help others write more useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) dx$$
Using $u$-substitution, we have
$$u=\frac{x}{2}\Rightarrow 2\ du=dx$$
So now
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan u\ du$$
$$=-2\ln\left|\cos \frac{\pi}{4}\right|+2\ln\left|\cos 0\right|$$
$$=-2\ln\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+2\ln 1$$
$$=-2\ln 1+2\ln \sqrt2+2\ln 1$$
$$=2\ln \sqrt2$$
$$=\ln 2$$

Answer (score 4):

If we set $x=2\arctan t$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\,dt = \left.\log(1+t^2)\right|_{0}^{1}=\color{red}{\log 2}$$
as wanted.

Comment: +1 I was about to post an answer with the Weierstrass sub (which allows you to "see it" immediately), but you beat me to the punch. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$tan(x/2) = \frac {sin(x/2)}{cos(x/2)}=-2\frac {(cos(x/2))'}{cos(x/2)}-=-2(ln(cos(x/2)))'$

Therefore:

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}tan(x/2) dx=-2ln(cos(\pi/4)) + 2ln(cos(0))=-2ln(1/\sqrt 2 )=ln2$

Comment: @Soroush To compensate $(x/2)'=1/2$

Answer (score 0):

Notice $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan\frac{x}{2}dx=\left[2\ln\left|\sec\frac{x}{2}\right|\right]_{0}^{\pi/2}$$ $$=2[\ln|\sec\frac{\pi}{4}|-\ln|\sec 0|]$$
$$=2[\ln|\sqrt 2|-\ln|1|]$$
$$=2\ln|\sqrt 2|=2\frac{1}{2}\ln 2=\ln 2$$